# python regex with optional group

Tags: python, regex

A newbie in regex here, I will appreciate any help.

```
cstring = "[0,90,(+45,45)3,0/]S"
regex = re.compile(r'^(\[)(\S+)(\/?)(\][ST]$)')
match = regex.search(cstring)
for s in match.groups():
    print s
```

The results are "[" "0,90,(+45,45)3,0/" "]S" but I would like to get "/" in a separate (and optional - the only one from the above) group. I've tried to replace \S with any combinations like [0-9(),+-] - (these are the only characters expected in the second group) but no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex quantity specifiers + and * are greedy, you can add a ? onto the end of them (+? and *?) to turn them into their non greedy forms.

Greedy means that the operator will try consume everything it can before checking the next token.

so for the case of

```
\S+\/?
```

The S will try consume everything it can before the / is checked, and as the / is optional nothing needs to be done for it.

Once we make it into its non greedy form

```
\S+?\/?
```

The S will consume as little as possible before trying the / meaning that the / gets 'first dibs' on any tokens, and once it fails to grab them these tokens will be tried against the \S+?

I found success using the following:

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(\[)(\S+?)(\/?)(\][ST]$)')
```

For more information you can see [the python re docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) search for greedy.

As a side note if you pass the re.VERBOSE flag into re.compile then it will ignore whitespace within your string meaning you can structure it as

```
regex = re.compile(r'^ (\[) (\S+?) (\/?) (\][ST]$) ', re.VERBOSE)
```

which I found quite helpful when learning regex.

Also you have the start of string token outside a group '^ ([' but the end of string token within a group '(][ST]$)', this shouldn't make a difference except to readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try using non-greedy matching on your `\S` characters. That group is engulfing your `/` character.

Changing your regex to this works for me:

```
cstring = "[0,90,(+45,45)3,0/]S"
regex = re.compile(r'^(\[)(\S+?)(\/?)(\][ST]$)')
match = regex.search(cstring)
for s in match.groups():
    print s
```

Comment: Thanks Blender, it is sorted now